# PDF (probability density function) of function of a random variable

Tags: probability

If I have $X \sim \mathcal{G}(n, \lambda)$ and $Y=n\tau + X$ where $n, \tau$ are constants, then whats the PDF of $Y$?

My guess is it will become something like:

$$(n\tau + X) \sim \mathcal{G}(n, \lambda)$$

so since $n, \tau$ are constants they do not affect the distribution

$$f(y) = \frac{\lambda^n}{\Gamma(n)} y^{n-1}e^{-\lambda y}$$

Am I correct?

---

**UPDATE**: Answer attempt

According to [here](http://www.statlect.com/subon2/dstfun1.htm),

If $Y = g(X)$ then $f(y) = f(g^{-1}(y))$

So in this case, $g^{-1}(y) = y - n \tau$ then

$$f(y) = f(g^{-1}(y)) = \frac{\lambda^n}{\Gamma(n)}(y-n\tau)^{n-1}e^{-\lambda(y-n\tau)}$$

Is it correct now?

Comment: Hint: Won't affect it much. But $y$ gets replaced by a close relative.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, ok I updated my answer with an attempt. So I used $f(y)=f(g^{-1}(y))$

Comment: Yes, fine now. Your random variable is a shifted Gamma. Shift, scaling are usually simple to do. One way to remember is from how the density of a shifted/scaled normal $\mu+\sigma Z$ is obtained from the density of the standard normal.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, in the linked question [@Did commented](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549950/does-this-reduce-to-finding-pdf-of-a-function-of-a-random-variable#comment1172861_549950) that the understanding that $Y = g(X)$ with $g(X)$ being increasing then $f(y)=f(g^{-1}(y))$ is wrong (in general). What do you make out of it? Is my answer right here just by coincidence?

Comment: Yes, it is very wrong for density, it is fine for cdf and then you need to differentiate. For the function $k+y$ the derivative is $1$, so you get the right thing, but sort of by luck.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, I am having problems differenciating the CDF back to PDF could you help me out ([in another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552348/how-to-differentiate-cdf-of-gamma-distribution-to-get-back-pdf)) I am missing the $\lambda^n$ term ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $Y = g(X)$ then $f(y) = f(g^{-1}(y))$

So in this case, $g^{-1}(y) = y - n \tau$ then

$$f(y) = f(g^{-1}(y)) = \frac{\lambda^n}{\Gamma(n)}(y-n\tau)^{n-1}e^{-\lambda(y-n\tau)}$$

Comment: You could (and should) just post the answer here, instead.