# Does this reduce to finding PDF of a function of a random variable?

Tags: probability

In the below question in image, there is a deterministic non-service period ($\tau$) between serving customers, and then time to serve a customer is given to be $t \sim \varepsilon(\lambda)$. I need to find the PDF of time between consecutive customers.

---

[image]

---

My initial attempt is this: since $\tau$ is constant, it affects the total time by a constant $\tau$ only. So it becomes $(t+\tau) \sim \varepsilon(\lambda)$ then, $f(T) = f(t+\tau) = \lambda e^{-\lambda(t+\tau)}$. But is this right?

---

Doing the 2nd part of the question, which I also have posted a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/549754/2006) about. I found that if $Y = g(X)$, then $\text{PDF}_y = f(g^{-1}(y))$. So in this case, it looks like $T = t + \tau$, then $g^{-1}(T) = T - \tau$ then $f(T) = \lambda e^{-\lambda(T - \tau)}$.

But which is correct? Not a math major, my intuition feels that the 1st attempt makes more sense but the 2nd seems to be correct answer ... can someone help me make sense of this? If the 2nd is correct, why might my initial attempt be wrong?

Comment: It seems that, from some time and on several MSE pages, you are asserting that, or asking about, the fact that the PDF $f_Y$ of $Y=g(X)$ would be given by $f_Y(y)=f_X(g^{-1}(y))$. Somebody should probably mention that this identity is **wrong** except when $g:x\mapsto x+c$.

Comment: @Did, or maybe I should have said for $g(x)$ being a strictly increasing function? As mentioned on [this site](http://www.statlect.com/subon2/dstfun1.htm). But even then, from the proof on that site, it isnt clear to me why it does not hold when its not strictly increasing

Comment: Suspicion confirmed: even when $g$ is increasing, the formula you suggest is deeply wrong (try $g(x)=2x$ to see what happens). And, unsurprisingly, this is not what the page you link to says (PDF $\ne$ CDF).

Comment: @Did, I am actually looking at [this part](http://i.imgur.com/qOGKgrg.png) of the page. Did I misunderstand that part?

Comment: Yes, you took a formula relating CDFs for a formula relating PDFs.

Comment: Err ... sry not really good in maths, but in the image, it says "*probability mass of an increasing function*". Probability mass is PDF right?

Comment: A [PMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) is for a discrete random variable . The analogue of the PMF for a continuous random variable is its PDF. Exponential random variables are continuous, not discrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the time between serving customers is $T$ with $T=t+\tau$ with $t$ having an exponential distribution with a PDF of $\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ for $x\ge 0$ and $\tau$ being constant,

- then $\Pr(t \le x)=1- e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x\ge 0$
- so $\Pr(t + \tau \le x+\tau)=1- e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x\ge 0$
- so $\Pr(T \le x+\tau)=1- e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x\ge 0$
- so $\Pr(T \le y)=1- e^{-\lambda (y-\tau)}$ for $y\ge \tau$
- so the PDF for $T$ is $\lambda e^{-\lambda (T-\tau)}$ for $T\ge \tau$

so your second formulation is correct

Comment: Err for the PDF is it more correct to write $f(y) = \lambda e^{-\lambda (y- \tau)}$?

Comment: @JiewMeng: Yes it is, and I should not have written $t$ having an exponential distribution with a PDF of $\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ either. Better to have written $f_t(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ and $f_T(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda(y-\tau)}$